# How display in json only one attribute of an entity in a oneToMany with itself?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have a class embedded herself with a oneToMany relationship:

```
@Entity
public class A {

  private String id;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<A> parents;
}
```

Thanks to the fetch, I can display easily the complete json of each parents.

But to avoid over data and loop, I would display only id of the item from "parents".

Any clues ? 
Thank you.

**EDIT:**

After answer of marians27, I think about the reverse problem, for PUT and POST. 
But how to do it for PUT/POST ?

By example, knowing that the object "embeded_id" is already in my database, I wanna pass to my API a json like :

```
{"A":
   {
   "id":"new_object_id",
   "parents":
     [{
     "id":"embeded_id"
     }]
   }
}
```

instead of :

```
{"object":
   {
   "id":"new_object_id",
   "parents":
     [{
     "id":"embeded_id",
     "parents":[{...}]
     }]
   }
}
```

Here is the solution I found from [here](http://www.davismol.net/2015/05/20/jackson-create-a-custom-json-deserializer-with-stddeserializer-and-jsontoken-classes/):

```
@Service
public class DeserializeA extends StdDeserializer<A> {

  @Autowired
  private IManager manager;

  public DeserializeA() {
    super(A.class);
  }

  public DeserializeA(Class<A> t) {
    super(t);
  }

  @Override
  public A deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext arg1)
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    String id = null;
    JsonToken currentToken = null;
    while ((currentToken = jp.nextValue()) != null) {
      switch (currentToken) {
        case VALUE_STRING:
          switch (jp.getCurrentName()) {
            case "id":
              id = jp.getText();
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }

    return manager.getAById(id);
  }
}
```

Comment: You want to keep your entity such as or you want to modify it for addressing your need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom serializer. First annotate field, so that it uses your custom serializer:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonSerialize(contentUsing = ParentSerializer.class)
private List<A> parents;
```

Then implement the serializer itself:

```
public class ParentSerializer extends StdSerializer<A> {
    public ParentSerializer() {
        super(A.class);
    }
    @Override
    public void serialize(A value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider  provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField("id", value.getId());
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed.